# ngModel fails when calling an object using key

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-forms

When trying to call `[(ngModel)]="object[key].value"` I am getting an error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'KEY' of undefined

This approach seems to have worked in angular. I am migrating some views over to angular2 and this doesn't want to work. The KEY doesn't exist yet but I need to create a object with it. Is there a correct way to do it?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="composedResponse[category].response_name">
    <option value="Public">Public</option>
    <option value="Private">Private</option>
</select>
```

and it's an empty object

```
public composedResponse: any= {};
```

Comment: please post the code of corresponding @Component

Comment: Hard to say without seeing code. But according to the error, `object` is what seems to be undefined.

Comment: Is `category` `null`?